# MATLAB: how to loop through my vector and round up or down

Tags: matlab, finance

I have to write up a code whereby I use Mean-variance optimization to rebalance my portfolio for 12 months (one year). The only thing is that I have to determine how I will round my number of assets after each rebalancing. When I round, I need to see if the difference between my new portfolio value (after subtracting transaction costs) and my old portfolio value is positive, up to a set limit of about $3000.00.

For example, my initial number of assets was:

```
x_int = [4500, 6000, 0, 0, 0, 500, 1550, 0, 1000, 0];
```

My new rebalanced number of assets for the first period was:

```
x_new = [2490.67, 4401.78, 1502.30, 0, 1010.45, 2803.85, 3489.77, 0, 650.98, 1001.87];
```

My initial portfolio value was $1,897,560.30

My rebalanced portfolio value for the first period came out as $1,658,923.76 (after I rounded all my asset numbers down) and as $2,001,876.95 (after I rounded all my asset numbers up).

Is there a way to loop through my `x_new` values, round up and/or down each individual number of assets and check to see if my rounded assets will give me a new portfolio value that, when I subtract from the initial portfolio value will satisfy my criteria

Thanks!

Comment: How does rounding make such a huge difference? I think you are not talking about this [`round`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) function, because `round(2490.67) = 2491`.

Comment: Yes, rounding can make a huge difference depending on the price of the stock. If the stock was worth $250.00 a share, then having 1000 or 1001 shares would be a significant price difference. I used ceil and floor functions since the round function will either round or down depending on the decimal value (which I didnt want)

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, maybe this: `sum(round(x_new))-sum(x_new)`?

Comment: My problem is that I do not know which of my assets from x_new need to be rounded up instead of down and vice versa. So if x_new(1) = 2490.67 is rounded up to 2491 and the rest of my assets is rounded down, then will the difference between my new portfolio value and old portfolio value be within the range of $0 to $3000.00 that need?? If not, then should I round x_new(1) = 2490.67 down to 2490 instead while I round everything up; will that work?? If not, then I will need to find some other permutation (maybe I need to round my first two assets up and everything down) until I reach my goal

Answer (score 0):

Since there would generally be more than one ways of adjusting the portfolio to 
meet the criterion, the answer would depend on what kind of adjustments you prefer. The following approach starts with rounding to nearest integer and then, if required to meet the budget, rounds some of the stocks to the opposite direction.

Let,

1. `price` be a vector the same size as `x_new` and represent the unit share price.
2. `budget` be the upper limit of the new portfolio value (i.e old portfolio value + 3000 + transaction costs).

Firstly, let's round the new portfolio stocks to nearest integer and compute the cost.

```
x_rnd    = round(x_new);
cost_rnd = x_rnd * price';
```

Depending on whether `cost_rnd` is above or below `budget` we would tweak the number of individual shares. If `cost_rnd` is under-budget, we would try to round-up some of the stocks that were rounded-down. Similarly, if `cost_rnd` is over-budget we would change some of the roundings from up to down.

```
cost_rnd = x_rnd * price';
if (cost_rnd > budget) % exceeds budget, so we need to round a few of them down
    x_adjust_dir = floor(x_new)-x_rnd;
    cum_adjust_cost = cost_rnd + cumsum(x_adjust_dir .* price);
    n_adjust = find(cum_adjust_cost < budget, 1, 'first');
elseif (cost_rnd < budget) % under-budget, so we should round a few of them up
    x_adjust_dir = ceil(x_new)-x_rnd;
    cum_adjust_cost = cost_rnd + cumsum(x_adjust_dir .* price);
    n_adjust = find(cum_adjust_cost < budget, 1, 'last');
else % by some miracle the budget is exactly met 
    n_adjust = [];
end
```

Note that some elements of `x_adjust_dir` would be zeros. They represent the shares that are already rounded in the right direction. The remaining elements would be `-1` for over-budget case and `1` for under-budget case. `cum_adjust_cost` is the cumulative change due to the rounding adjustments. `n_adjust` is the index of the cumulative adjustment that puts the adjusted cost just below the budget.

Now all that remains is to apply the adjustments:

```
x_final = x_rnd;
if ~isempty(n_adjust)
    x_final(1:n_adjust) = x_final(1:n_adjust) + x_adjust_dir(1:n_adjust);
end
```

`x_final` is the adjusted portfolio that meets the criterion.

Comment: Hey @aksadv, thanks for the rounding code, it works!! But, I am having problems with the budget aspect in that my new portfolio value always seems to come out incorrectly. For example: if my "old portfolio value" = 1,000,000.00 (before re-balancing) and my transaction costs sum up to $7,500.00 (transaction costs are 0.5% of the unit price for each asset sold or bought).....then my re-balanced portfolio value (using x_new) is around 1,006,988.31 which, if I remove the recalculated transaction costs and $3000.00 limit, leaves me below my budget. Is there something wrong??

Comment: Sorry, I made a small mistake, my re-balanced portfolio value (using x_final) is around 1,006,988.31

Comment: What was the budget in this example? What was the gap between the x_final value and the budget? Would it be possible for you to share the example?